# mingw on Ubuntu - "undefined references"... to its own functions

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, undefined-reference

I am trying to set up a script that automatically builds a small library I'm trying to write for whichever archs/OSs I want to include in the package all in one go. At the moment, just x86_64 Linux and Windows. I have no problem compiling the code for x86_64 Linux with g++ (not surprising). It's partly a practice exercise for myself.

However, I am having difficulty with the mingw-w64 linker. I decided to try building a "hello world" to see if it was an issue with my dependencies. I had the same problem.

The last command:

```
CXXFLAGS_WIN64="-Wall -O3 -m64 -std=c++11 -pedantic"
LINKFLAGS_MINGW64_EXE="-Wall -m64 -pedantic -L ${MINGW64_DIR}/lib" 
INCLUDEDIR_MINGW64=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include

#Build
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ${CXXFLAGS_WIN64} -I ${includedir} -I ${INCLUDEDIR_MINGW64} -c ${srcdir}/helloworld0.cpp -o ${OBJ_TARG_DIR}/helloworld0.o

#Link
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ${LINKFLAGS_MINGW64_EXE} -v -o helloworld0.exe ${OBJ_TARG_DIR}/helloworld0.o
```

outputs:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --libexecdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --with-headers=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --enable-lto --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --enable-libatomic --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-dependency-tracking
Thread model: win32
gcc version 9.3-win32 20200320 (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-m64' '-Wpedantic' '-L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib' '-v' '-o' 'helloworld0.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccFdueja.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o helloworld0.exe /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/crtbegin.o -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib ./obj/win64/helloworld0.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/crtend.o
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o: in function `__tmainCRTStartup':
./build/x86_64-w64-mingw32-x86_64-w64-mingw32-crt/./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:288: undefined reference to `__mingw_init_ehandler'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o: in function `WinMainCRTStartup':
./build/x86_64-w64-mingw32-x86_64-w64-mingw32-crt/./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:194: undefined reference to `__security_init_cookie'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o: in function `mainCRTStartup':
./build/x86_64-w64-mingw32-x86_64-w64-mingw32-crt/./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:222: undefined reference to `__security_init_cookie'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Most of this is the result of the -v flag for informational purposes, but the linker issue appears to be that it cannot resolve references to two functions: `__security_init_cookie` and `__mingw_init_ehandler`.

This was already odd as it was mingw's own modules that were calling these functions, but I thought I'd check for a missing library.
Nope. Upon snooping through the libraries in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib`, I found exports of these functions in `libmingw32.a`. Which as you can see in the verbose output appears to be explicitly included as `-lmingw32` in the expanded mingw command!

So what gives? Is `-lmingw32` incompatible with a 64-bit build? If so, why put it in the x86_64 directory and why isn't a 64-bit version included? Is mingw putting the libraries in the wrong order? Is there a circular dependency?

Anyway, I'm hoping there is just an issue with my configuration and this isn't something I am going to have to wait on mingw to fix. If anyone sees what's wrong, let me know! I didn't find much in terms of search results for my particular scenario so that makes me think I just messed up something obvious. It does seem odd though that mingw is having trouble resolving its own dependencies, so I worry I messed up something in the installation somehow? (I used apt-get...)

Using mingw-w64 version 9.3.0 on 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.1 (arch amd64).

I'm going to continue poking around to see if I can figure out the dependency chain of this whole CRT thing. And of course if there is already a good post on this that I missed, feel free to link.

If you had the chance to read this through, thanks!

-B

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. -lmingw32 does not work, but adding `-Wl,--no-whole-archive /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a` to the command line resolves the issue and my project is linked successfully.

I cann't realise the difference between -lmingw32 and specifying the full path. They should be identical, but the second one works and the first one does not